# Are there performance benefits of one-way binding in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

When reading about one-way binding in `angular.component` style, I came across multiple statements that `<` vs `=` produces less watchers (`=` will have additional watcher to propagate value change from child to parent).

However I've just created a dummy component, passed the object to it via `=` and `<` and number of watchers is the same.

So speaking strictly about performance: are there any diffirence between `<` and `=` ?

Comment: @Arashsoft As of today (July 2018),I see no mention on the number of watches on the doc you link to. Perhaps they removed an incorrect information?

Comment: @PhiLho, thank you, I removed my comment but still I think it should have one less watch because it does not monitor child changes.

Comment: @Arashsoft I am not sure, but I think there is only one watch, whatever the source of change: a watch examines, on a digest phase, if the value changed from the one in the previous phase. The fact the change comes from the parent or the child is probably not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

I came here with the same question, and was disappointed to see no answer...
I have a small test application where I use all kinds of binding, three of them being one-way. I observed the number of watches (using [ng-stats utility](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats)), got 42.
I changed these `"<"` to `"="`, which changed the behavior of my app accordingly, of course. ng-stats still reported 42 watches.
So, at least in terms of watches, this brings no performance improvement.

I guess it is here more as a convenience, avoiding unwanted side effects (child changing a value, parent's value being changed unwillingly) and promoting good practices (using bound functions instead of watches, as explained below).

It can still be a way to avoid watches: a common practice when a parent wants to be advised of changes in a child it is to use two-way binding, set up a watch on the value, and react on changes.
An alternative is to set up a one-way binding (to feed the child), and to provide a callback (via a `"&"` binding), and thus to let the child to notify of changes via this callback.
It is more proactive and it removes a watch.